# Symbols in VS-compiled Binaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, binary, symbols

I have the following question: 
Is it possible to find symbols in a Visual Studio compiled C++ binary or are symbols only ever stored in either .pdb or .map files? If they can be found in a binary, what settings determine if symbols are stored there?

Or to put it another way: is it possible for the binary to contain any part of the source code, be it members, functions or what ever.

Thanks

Comment: A DLL would contain the names of exported functions and variables, at a minimum. A DLL and an EXE would contain names that they expect to be resolved from other DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose when building whether to embed the debug information in the library instead of the pdb - see /Z7 in [Debug Information Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx). So if you ship .libs or .objs this can be an issue. When the final exe/dll is created however this information will not be there - it will be put into a PDB.

DLL exported functions and variables will be named so callers can find them.

Code which use `__FUNCTION__` and `__FILE__` macros will probably mean string literals for these values will be somewhere in the final executable. This goes for all other string literals in the code - they'll be in there somewhere.

Apart from this there wont be much information about the original code in the final dll/exe.

Comment: If you use the older .def file method of specifying exports (rather than __declspec(dllexport) you can still export by ordinal along with NONAME and not have even the names be exported.

Answer (score 1):

To find symbols in DLL, EXE, LIB or OBJ files build in Windows COFF format, please use dumpbin.exe utility, it is typically included in the SDK or WDK, or shipped with VC++

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference

For example, running it with /ALL option on simple exe will produce list of symbols in .exe to be resolved from DLLs. Running it on DLL will produce list of symbols exported by DLL.

MSVCP140.dll
         140003080 Import Address Table
         140003AD0 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

```
                 103 ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@M@Z                         
                 10C ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@_K@Z                        
                 10D ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@_N@Z                        
                 4C5 ?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAXH_N@Z                          
                 368 ?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@XZ                      
                 244 ?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAXXZ                            
                 4DE ?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAHD@Z                         
                 4E1 ?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA_JPEBD_J@Z                   
                 2B4 ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A                               
                 51F ?uncaught_exceptions@std@@YAHXZ
```

VCRUNTIME140.dll
         1400030D8 Import Address Table
         140003B28 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

```
                  3E memset                                                                                 
                   8 __C_specific_handler                                                                   
                  23 __std_terminate                                                                        
                   E __CxxFrameHandler3
```

Comment: Very usefule tool, thanks. :) 

Though the /ALL option just dumps and endless stream which looks like a hex view, hexa on the left and ASCII on the right.

Comment: @ruhigbrauner well, /HEADERS might work better for you